# Setting Spark-2.2.1 as default execution engine for apache-hive-2.1.1

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

Hadoop 2.7.3, Spark 2.2.1 and Hive 2.1.1.

Hive log shows that java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/JavaSparkListener when I try to load data to any of the tables.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.JavaSparkListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 19 more
```

What can be the issue ? These was a spark bug fix for the similar issue which says spark 2.2.0 should have the solution . My question is when I am using spark 2.2.1 then why even I am getting this issue .The requested jar should already be inside the spark core jar in the classpath .

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, can you please let me know how you solved this. I have even tried editing hive script to add sparks jars in the classpath, and although I could see from the hive logs that the spark jars are being distributed, I still see this no class def found exception